# Bootstrap Tooltips set custom title messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my project, I use Bootstrap Tooltips like this:

```
$(function () {
        $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
    //So if I hove over delete, I'll get the delete tooltips message.
    });
```

**then**

```
<a rel="tooltip" title="This is a very long tooltip message!" data-placement="right">test</a>
```

Is it possible to somehow do all this so that I don't have to include the tooltip message in the link there? Instead I'd like to keep the tooltip text elsewhere and use it based on what the tooltip is.

**For Example:**

```
<a rel="tooltip" class="Delete">Link 1</a>
<a rel="tooltip" class="Add">Link 2</a>

deleteMsg = "Click to delete this folder";
addMsg = "Click to add a folder";

$(function () {
  $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
});
```

How can something like this be done?

Comment: @SurjithSM: This is a jQuery/Bootstrap question. What does PHP have to do with any of this?

Comment: @SurjithSM Yes, I'm using PHP

Comment: @jmenezes I thought you can do this dynamically with PHP

Answer (score 4):

You could put all your tooltips into an object keyed on the class of the element. Something like this:

```
var tooltips = {
    Delete: 'Click to delete this folder',
    Add: 'Click to add a folder'
}

$(function () {
    $("[rel='tooltip']").each(function() {
        $(this).tooltip({
            title: tooltips[$(this).prop('class')];
        });
    });
});
```

While this may work and is arguably a better separation of concerns, it is *horrifically* ugly, and very easily broken by simply changing a class property.

I would recommend you stick with the default method of putting the tooltip in the `title` attribute of the element. That also has the benefit of working for people browsing your website with javascript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the tooltip variables based on the class name

```
<a rel="tooltip" class="delete" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a rel="tooltip" class="add" href="#">Link 2</a>

<script>
var deleteMsg = "Click to delete this folder";
var addMsg = "Click to add a folder";

$(function () {
    $("[rel='tooltip']").each(function () {
        $(this).tooltip({ title: eval($(this).attr('class') + "Msg") });
    });
});
</script>
```